# Is there a better way to get the value from a jQuery.each()?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I want to iterate through all of my kendoDatePicker elements. 
I got it to work, but it seems extremely ugly.
Is there a better, way to do this?

```js
    var aryNewCalendar = [];

    $(".g-datepicker").each(function () {
        var id = $(this)[0].id;
        if (id.substring(0,2) === "dp")
            {
            aryNewCalendar.push({
                Text: $(this)[0].value
            });
        }
    });
    return aryNewCalendar;
```

I am iterating through all of the elements with the '.g-datepicker' class, but it appears that the 'wrapper' is also identified.

I don't like the whole **$(this)[0].id** approach, it seems "unstable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)[0].id;` is the  same as doing `this.id` with exception that you first wrap `this` in `$()` and then pull it back out from the resultant jQuery object. Same with `$(this)[0].value`

Just do `this.id` and `this.value`.

There is no reason it would be unstable though, just redundant

---

Not at all clear what you mean by *"the wrapper is also identified"*

---

You might also be able to simplify it to:

```
var aryNewCalendar = $(".g-datepicker[id*=dp]").map(function(){
   return {
       Text: this.value           
   }
}).get()
```

This assumes that none of the other ID's within that class contain "dp" anywhere in them

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I guess I was getting a little jQuery happy.
Your simplified version worked perfectly and is much more straightforward and elegant. Thank you.

Comment: Thought I did that, I must've clicked it twice. Thanks again